# Angular: npm doesn't serve assets folder

Tags: angular, assets

I want to include a sample file for developing in my `assets` folder (`src/assets/articles_ziege.csv`). But somehow the configuration fails. I think its related with the localization but don't know :-/ Reading different threads I thought

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
       ...
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
```

would do it. But somehow it doesn't. Any hints what I'm missing?

The full `angular.json` could be found [here](https://github.com/leomayer/1korn-leo/blob/main/angular.json).

Comment: This should work, "src/assets" is shorthand for glob everything in that folder https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration, can you detail how you know it doesn't work, i.e. you're sure it's not copied into dist/ folder on build

Comment: thx for the help - I figured out that the main problem is related with localization, which served on a different path :-/

Comment: @Leo, I think that If your assets folder are in `/1korn-leo/en/` and `/1korn-leo/de/` you use `httpClient.get('assest/articles_ziege.csv',{responseType: 'text'})`, if your assets folder are in `/1korn-leo/` use `httpClient.get('/assest/articles_ziege.csv',{responseType: 'text'})`

Comment: @Eliseo you might want to recheck this comment

Comment: @Eliseo: I think you wanted to point out the different folders, i.e. `assest/en/articles_ziege.csv` vs. `assest/articles_ziege.csv` - at least this I figured out finally was the game changer. So thx again for helping.

Comment: yes, to point out assets/articles_ziege.cvs you write `/assets/..`, to point to assest/en/articles_ziege.csv you remove the `/` and write `assets/...`

Answer (score 0):

the location is correct the only things you maybe didn't do is: killing terminal in every change on the angular.json and restart

Comment: Already done - more than once. You can see as well on my github-page..

Comment: which version of  angular and node you use  ?

Comment: thx for the help - I figured out that the main problem is related with localization, which served on a different path :-/